WIN32 game loop is slow, can't handle 60HZ or 30HZ. What to do?
I'm just trying to learn to program a few things, and a game loop is one of those.
This game loop only process Windows messages, but it can not even handle 30 fps.
This is true also if the message processing is done only once per loop, replacing WHILE with IF.
I use QueryPerformanceCounter() function to get number of 100ns ticks before work is done and after, subtracting them to get time used. Loop time is 100ns * 166666 * 2 = 0.0333332s.
The boolean 'timeExceeded' is set if the the wait time is positive, indicating that time used is more than the intended loop time.
What to do?
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // windows class information
    static const wchar_t class_name[] = L"Test";
    WNDCLASS wc{ };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = class_name;
    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return 0;

    // Get correct windows size based on disered client area
    RECT client_rect;
    client_rect.left = 0;
    client_rect.top = 0;
    client_rect.right = 800;
    client_rect.bottom = 600;
    if (!AdjustWindowRect(&client_rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE))
        return 0;

    // create windows
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, class_name, L"Test",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_OVERLAPPED,
        100, 100, -client_rect.left + client_rect.right, -client_rect.top + client_rect.bottom,
        0, 0, hInstance, 0
    );
    if (hwnd == 0)
        return 0;



    // Show Window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // Timer & setup
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency))
        return 0;
    if (frequency.QuadPart != 10000000LL)
        return 0;

    HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
    if (hTimer == 0)
        return 0;


    // timer data
    LARGE_INTEGER start_time;
    LARGE_INTEGER end_time;
    LARGE_INTEGER rest_time;
    LARGE_INTEGER loop_time;
    loop_time.QuadPart = -166666LL*2;   // loop time

    bool timeExceeded = false;      // does time exceeds loop time


    // message loop data
    MSG msg = { };
    bool running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        // measure time
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&start_time))
            break;

        // process messages
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                running = false;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        // other work

        // Get elapsed time and wait for 30hz - elapsed time
        if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&end_time))
            break;

        rest_time.QuadPart = loop_time.QuadPart + (end_time.QuadPart - start_time.QuadPart);
        if (rest_time.QuadPart >= 0)
        {
            timeExceeded = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &rest_time, 0, 0, 0, 0))
            break;

        if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != 0)
            break;
    }

    // clean up
    CloseHandle(hTimer);
    
    return 0;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


Why not just time things individually until you find the source of the slowdown.  I'm not a Windows expert, but this should definitely be possible. Also, you could use rdtsc to get a more fine-grained timer.

It can easily take over 1/30 of a second to repaint a window with the standard WinAPI functions.

That's why Microsoft came up with DirectX.

@Mark Rnasom Well before you do DirectX, Direct2D/3D you would need a window, and a game loop like I have done, or? If I have written this program wrong I would like a answer what I have done wrong. It can't be correct

You haven't shown enough code to see exactly what you're doing wrong.  My guess is that you're relying on WM_PAINT to draw your screen.

@Mark Ransom You can look at the now

The code as written can't be faster than 0.046875 seconds.  Problem is the resolution provided by SetWaitableTimer(), the timer completes at a clock interrupt.  Which ticks 64 times per second by default, once every 15.625 millisecond.  166666LL*2 was an unlucky choice, even if the loop takes no time at all, you'll still wait 3 * 15.625 = 46.875 milliseconds for the timer to wake up.  Beyond picking a better wait time, you can call timeBeginPeriod() to make the timer more accurate.

Yep, debug builds can be horrifically slow. They're compiled to make debugging easier. Release code is highly optimized and often the output looks like your code went through a blender, everything shuffled around, reordered, and mashed together for the best possible speed. Debug build generally takes the simplest, most direct path translating your code into a program

@Hans Passant According to the documentation of SetWaitableTimer : lpDueTime = The time after which the state of the timer is to be set to signaled, in 100 nanosecond intervals

A traditional game loop doesn't try to self-throttle to a particular frame rate. Rather, it tries to render as fast as possible and measure the time between frames to compute how to update the game.  That is, on each iteration of the render loop, you measure how much time is elapsed since the last iteration. Then update your game objects (motion, animations, etc...) to reflect this amount of elapsed time.

The resolution of the timer parameter is not necessarily related to the resolution of the timer itself.  Just because it allows you to specify 100 ns intervals doesn't mean it will use them.

Are you mixing C and C++?  I highly recommend you picking one language, C or C++ and program in it.  The C++ language allows for function and operator overloading, as well as inheritance and exceptions.  These items are difficult to mix with C because the C language doesn't have these items.  Once you decide on a single language, update your languagetags.

If you haven't done so already, read up on Windows timer resolution.  One starting point is this blog article: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2021/01/29/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change-2/

"Precision" and "resolution" are different things. The precision of the timer is 100 ns. The resolution, however, is 1/64th s.

While the direct answer is timer resolution, your code also has a whole bunch of other problems. You need to be more careful and deliberate with what you write, for example your message loop is incorrect because it is, well, not a loop.

@dialer while(running) is clearly a loop, and its body repeatedly dequeues messages and dispatches them. The loop may be inappropriate in processing one message at most, but it is still correct.

However, you need a swap-buffer/swap-chain to deal well with your window and having the full customization, it depends on which API you dealing with, OpenGL has it own way, directX12 has it own way, or even SFML which present a simple 2d graphic buffer system.
From what I saw in your code there's no graphic API, you need to set a buffer system (like what I said swap-chain or swap-buffer) for the window, then think about testing how much the window gives us frame per second.

another point i want to talk about, your way to calculate the FPS is not the best way,
i prefer to use msi afterburner (wich will make your program while msi afterburner is running use more MBs ram but it's ok)

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. An answer must answer the question asked. This one doesn't. Please take the [tour].

Agree with previous comments that the code as written is limiting the frame rate to 30FPS. If the goal is to write a game timer, then I suggest looking at existing QPC-based timer classes from Luna's Intro To 3D Game Programming with DirectX series of books, or the StepTimer.h class from @ChuckWalbourn for use with DirectX apps. A Windows message loop with no work to do should be running at well over 5000fps. With a correct timer, even an app that just clears a device context (DC) with BitBlt() (to BLACKNESS for example) should be faster than 5000fps.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
